# R 3.1.2 formatting (converting) Zulu time

Tags: r

I'm using R3.1.2. I have some zulu time series data

```
2011-03-08 08:00:06.6000000Z
2011-03-08 08:00:06.7000000Z
2011-03-08 08:00:06.8000000Z
```

and so on (100ms time series). Which pattern should I use in order to get 2011-03-08 08:00:06.800?

Comment: Explain your question with more words.

Comment: This is probably one of the most unclear questions I've ever seen.

Comment: I need date pattern format that should give me also the milliseconds of the input date. In the question, the given value 2011-03-08 08:00:06.800 should be obtained after parsing the date format on the  2011-03-08 08:00:06.8000000Z.

Answer (score 0):

I could not create a format string that worked directly on that format but this succeeds in delivering what I think you may need:

```
dat <- c("2011-03-08 08:00:06.6000000Z",
 "2011-03-08 08:00:06.7000000Z",
 "2011-03-08 08:00:06.8000000Z")
 strptime( substr(dat,1,23), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
#[1] "2011-03-08 08:00:06 GMT" "2011-03-08 08:00:06 GMT"
#[3] "2011-03-08 08:00:06 GMT"
```